# Python 'RequestsHandler' object has no attribute 'filters'

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, attributeerror

I made a HTTP request handler that uses a queue to allow it to use asyncio.

```
class RequestsHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, loop):
        self._queue = queue.Queue
        loop.create_task(self._drain_loop())

    def emit(self, record):
        log_entry = self.format(record)
        self._queue.put(log_entry)

    async def _drain_loop(self):
        while True:
            log_entry = self._queue.get()
            payload = {
                'text': log_entry
            }
            await requests.post(
                'https://example.com/foo/bar',
                data=payload)

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = RequestsHandler(loop=asyncio.get_event_loop())
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

However, when I run `logger.info('a log message')`, it returns:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'RequestsHandler' object has no attribute 'filters'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Bills answer, however I would recommend you to use properly functions of inheritance with function `super()`

```
class RequestHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, loop):
        super(RequestHandler, self).__init__()
```

In empty `__init__()` you can define level of the handler with  parameter `level`, eg. `level = logging.WARNING` ...

Answer (score 1):

Your `RequestHandler` constructor should call the `logging.Handler` constructor.

```
class RequestsHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, loop):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        ...
```

That, in turn, calls the `Filterer` constructor, which is what initializes the `filters` attribute to an empty list.